# Gas consumed by function invoking event?

Tags: gas-estimate

I have a function to emit event. When I check Ganache, I find that gas used is 23078. Doesn't the event consume less gas than function with contract state change operations?

```
function log() {
    CheckUserAccess("John_Wick","Create",false);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if i understood your question right, but 23078 gas is corresponding to 21000 standard gas price for a transaction + 2078 for calling the Event.

2078 gas is definitely less expensive than the gas normally used for a function call.